# My CSS grid layout causes horizontal scroll and I can't figure out why

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

Working with CSS grid layout, my page display a slight overflow in the X axis.I have deleted the grid and then the overflow disappears. When I reset the grid the overflow reappears. So I'm wondering why that occurs ?

- I have tried to set the max-width to `100vw` or less : doesn't work
- I have tried to set margin and padding to zero or less: doesn't work
- even overflow-x °as a workaround°  doesn't work
- I have try to set grid column gutters to 0: doesn't work
- I have reset again explicitly for my React Component, the div element with margin and padding to zero : doesn't work.
- I have tried to set a grid_container with max-width to 100vw: doesn't work
- I have tried to change div in span elements: doesn't work

In fact I have two grids, one on a layout level, another on the layouts elements level. 
Here an image of my current situation:

[image]

As you can see, seems I have two problems:

- a column occupies all the page width space and the secon column on the overflow
- a structural overflow due to some weird behaviors.

Here my layout.js :

```
export default ({children, title = 'title' }) => (
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <div className={style.layout}> 
            <Head>
                <title>{ title }</title>
                <meta charSet='utf-8' />
                <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' />
            </Head>
            <HeadComponent/>  
            <div className={style.signature}>
                signature 
            </div>
            <div className={style.social_medias}>
                social_medias 
            </div>
            <div className={style.children}>
                {children} 
            </div>
            <Footer className={style.footer}/>  
        </div>
    </Provider>
)
```

here my layout.css :

```
html, body{ 
    margin : 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%; 
}
.layout{ 
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; 
    margin:auto;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    display : grid; 
    grid-template-areas:  
                "header   header"
                "signature social_medias"
                "children children"
                "footer   footer" ;
    grid-template-rows: 44px 0.5fr 1fr auto ;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 

}


.centerbar{  
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: orange ;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.headbar{ 

    grid-area: header; 
    display :grid ; 
    z-index:170;
    margin: auto; 
    width:100vw; 
    position:fixed;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
}


.signature{ 
    grid-area: signature;
}
.logo:hover{ 
    color: black;
}


.social_medias{ 
    grid-area: social_medias;
}


/*** children ***/

.children{ 
    background-color: pink;
    grid-area: children; 
    height: 100%;
}


/*** footer ***/ 
/* 
.footer{  
    grid-area: footer; 
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;  
     margin-top: 10em;  

} */
```

Here my css file :

```
  .footer_grid{   
    grid-area: footer;  
    height: 100vh;    
    max-width: 100vw; 
    padding:0; 
    margin-top: 10vh;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas:  
                " let_chat     social_medias"
                " citations    email_form   " ;
    grid-template-columns: 2.5fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto; 
    background-color: white;  
    border-top: solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 25px;  
    grid-column-gap: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 157);
} 

.let_chat{ 
grid-area: let_chat;
font-family: "Moonlight";
font-size: 90pt;
display : flex; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center
}

.social_medias{ 
grid-area: social_medias; 
display : flex; 
justify-content: end; 
align-items: start;
}

.citations{ 
    grid-area: citations; 
}

.email_form{ 
    grid-area: email_form; 
}
```

Here my React.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import style from "./Footer.css";

export default () => {
  return ( 
      <span className={style.footer_grid}>
              <div className={style.let_chat}>
              let chat
              </div>
              <div className={style.social_medias}>
              social media
              </div>
              <div className={style.citations}>
              citations
              </div>
              <div className={style.email_form}>
              email form
              </div>
      </span> 
  )
}
```

I'm wondering what is wrong. If someone has any hint, would be great.

Comment: Can you demo this?

Comment: Okay here a repo : https://github.com/Hocoh/grid_css_overflow => To make this example work, just git clone the repository, then run :

    yarn install, then
    yarn dev

Comment: No...github links aren't appropriate nor should we need to install anything. You need to demo this **in the question**.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay I will create my snippet

Answer (score 2):

Include `box-sizing: border-box;` in `.footer_grid`. Basically what it does is that includes the border into the width. Otherwise, your grid will be wider than `100vw`, which brings the horizontal scroller.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `width` from `100vw` to `100%`?

Comment: I have just rebuilt all my grid and put the root grid in a wrapper, now its work like a charm

Comment: my workaround is to set the wrapper to 99vw since box-sizing: border-box; is without effect for now, I'm still wondering where this behavior come since there is no border set anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some troubles like you with Grids and the horizontal scrollbar that appears. I managed to do this but I dont really know how it works.

I tried to created a one column page for a fullscreen hero image so I use:

```css
main{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100vw;
    grid-template-rows:15vh 85vh;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "hero";
    width: 100%;
}
```

And it create an horizontal scrollbar, but if I use this:

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(0,100vw);
```

It dissapears the horizontal scrollbar, somewhere I read that it have to do with the default value of auto somewhere. Hope it help!

Comment: Well this solved my issue but now I'm still wondering how does it work.